# SPF - DNS TXT, SMTP RELAY Woes

Tags: email, dns, spf

```
" Slowly, as time goes on we are getting more messages lost in spam filters that we are sending to clients.
```

I think it's because our SPF isn't set right."

Trouble shooting and error Reports:

I used the SPF wizard from:
http://www.spfwizard.net/

From kitterman.com:

http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

**ISP**  used to block some info....

[The TXT records found for your domain are:
    "v=spf1 mx a ip4:216.216.123.224.168/24 a:209.**My outgoing WAN IP**.2 include:cidc.telus.com ~all"

Checking to see if there is a valid SPF record.

No valid SPF record found of either type TXT or type SPF.]

**Internally** we send outgoing mail to 192.168.1.3, (it's a barracuda) it then sends to our ISP relay (smtp.**ISP**.net)

Our MX records seem fine. but the MX records are nto the senders of the outbound emails.

If I pull the header from a received email:

```
[Received: from smtp01.cidc.telus.com (smtp01.cidc.telus.com. [216.123.224.168])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id rr4si1383765pac.48.2014.10.09.10.18.03
    for <**"ME"**@gmail.com>;
    Thu, 09 Oct 2014 10:18:04 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: permerror (google.com: domain of **"ME"@"company"**.ca uses a      mechanism     not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms: )) client-ip=216.123.224.168;
```

Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           spf=permerror (google.com: domain of **"ME"@"company"**.ca uses a mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms: )) smtp.mail=**"ME"@"company"**.ca
Received: (qmail 25065 invoked from network); 9 Oct 2014 17:18:03 -0000
Received: from host2.**"WAN IP"**.209.in-addr.arpa (HELO smtp.**"company"**.ca) (209.**"WAN IP"**.2)]

Kinda Pulling my hair out on this....  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your SPF policy contains a syntax error. Such errors result in SPF "permerror", meaning the SPF evaluation fails. This alone should not cause your email to be blacklisted, but you may not receive a higher reputation score that might come with SPF "pass". In this sense, an invalid SPF policy may cause lower deliverability.

In any case, if your policy is anything like the one you posted

```
v=spf1 mx a ip4:216.216.123.224.168/24 a:<valid-ip> include:cidc.telus.com ~all"
```

then the issue is likely that the `ip4` mechanism argument network-spec is invalid (`216.216.123.224.168/24` should be just `216.123.224.168/24`).

Also, the `a` mechanism argument must be a domain expression and not an IPv4 address, because the `a` mechanism verifies if the IP address being tested is among the IPs for the `a` mechanism argument domain.

If your actual SPF policy is different, please update your question with the current policy string and possibly the domain name to see how it is represented in DNS.